# Using ajax/jsonp to submit to another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am using ajax to submit data from a marketing website running on wordpress, to an application I am developing (currently running locally).

I am using the following code to submit the form data and handle the response:

```
jQuery("#error-message").html("");
    jQuery("#Submit").attr('disabled','disabled');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:21263/Register/CreateAccountAJAX",

        // the name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
        jsonp: "callback",

        // tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",

        // tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
        data: jQuery( "#SignupForm" ).serialize(),

        // work with the response
        success: function( response ) {
        alert(response);
            if(this.status == "success")
                window.location = "http://www.domain.com/signup-success";
            else
            {
                jQuery("#Submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                jQuery("#error-message").html(this.message);
            }
        }
    })
```

The form is posting to the server fine, however, I am unable to handle the response. There are a few possible replies - both listed below:

```
{ "status" : "success" }
{ "status" : "error", "message" : "The email address is already exists" }
```

In either case the `success` function does not run, and nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Comment: What console says, any error, message?

Comment: Do you know the exact response that you're getting back? Do you expect a simple JSON string like you've provided?

Comment: what I provided is the response that I get back. I just tried one with an invalid email address, and got the error `Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token :`

Comment: If you're using those ajax params (`jsonp` and `dataType`), I would have thought the replies from the server should look like `jQueryXXXXXXXX({ "status" : "success" })` or `jQueryYYYYYYYYYYYY({ "status" : "error", "message" : "The email address is already exists" })`. If you set `jsonpCallback: "myFunc"` then it should return `myFunc({ "status" : "success" })`.

Comment: And just to confirm - the `alert(response);` line never gets called, does it?

Comment: no, it doesn't get called

Comment: Yes, so your web app needs to take the value from the URL parameter `callback` that was passed via ajax, and you should use that function call to wrap the data that you pass back. So if the parameter is `callback=myFunction` the response from your webapp should be something like `myFunction({ "status" : "success" })`.